Radically smaller overall score compared to split test scores
I am training several models using sklearn's GridSearchCV on a regression task. The data is already split into 5 equally sized folds. When using SVR and MLP everything looks fine. However, when using RandomForestRegressor, I am getting drastically smaller overall scores compared to split test scores.
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,cv =CVs,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',n_jobs=-1)
grid_search.fit(X,y)
grid_score = -grid_search.score(X,y)
print('Overall score', grid_score)

# Showing results of cross validation
columns_of_interest = ['params','mean_test_score','std_test_score'] + [f'split{i}_test_score' for i in range(5)]
display(pd.DataFrame({col: grid_search.cv_results_[col] for col in columns_of_interest}))


Since I am using equally sized folds, I am expecting results to be roughly the same as is the case with SVR and MLP. I would gladly inspect the model's performance on the test set but unfortunately, It is not available.

The probable problem was that GridSearch was doing refitting on the entire dataset which includes data points that are mutually connected (different instances about the same patient). It might be the case that RandomForest was better at overfitting entire dataset then SVR and MLP
